# Suborder where fields are 0

Tags: mysql

So i can't find an answer to this question, i have the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM bans
WHERE
    removed = 0
AND
    (
        (`time` + `length` - UNIX_TIMESTAMP()) > 0
    OR
        length = 0
    )
ORDER BY length = 0,(`time` + `length` - UNIX_TIMESTAMP())
```

It gets all bans from a table and orders them according to when they are going to be unbanned. But bans with a length of 0 are permanent banned and they should be at the bottom of the list. Which already works. But i'd like those permanent bans to be ordered descending by banid. Which doesn't currently they are as default ordered ascending.

And if i put asc in it the hole order is screwed

Database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rp_bans` (
  `banid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `steamid` text NOT NULL,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  `adminid` text NOT NULL,
  `aname` text NOT NULL,
  `reason` text NOT NULL,
  `time` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `length` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `removed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`banid`)
)
```

Example data:

```
id  time    length  current time    timeleft
1   1365410228  0       1365411228  -1000
2   1365410229  3600    1365411228  2601
3   1365410230  0       1365411228  -998
4   1365410231  84000   1365411228  83003
5   1365410232  3600    1365411228  2604
6   1365410233  0       1365411228  -995
7   1365410234  800000  1365411228  799006
```

Expected result:

```
id  time    length  current time    timeleft
2   1365410229  3600    1365411228  2601
5   1365410232  3600    1365411228  2604
4   1365410231  84000   1365411228  83003
7   1365410234  800000  1365411228  799006
6   1365410233  0       1365411228  -995
3   1365410230  0       1365411228  -998
1   1365410228  0       1365411228  -1000
```

So if length is not 0 then a order by timeleft ascending (which is calculated from time + length - current time). When length is 0 it needs to be ordered by id descending behind the entries where length is not 0.

Comment: Show us some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: What do you mean by *where ever length = 0 Descending*? Descending on which property?

Comment: Hope this clears it up, all rows with length = 0 need to be ordered DESC by banid or time (would give the same effect) and they need to be behind the other where length <> 0

Comment: i updated the initial question so i hope it clarifies is better

Comment: I am trying a little now, and it looks like MySQL sorts negative numbers **towards** zero. Just sorting on "timeleft" could do the trick.

Comment: True but that is where my problem starts. The first part of the query needs to be ordered ascending on timeleft. The last part needs to be descending. I was thinking to create 2 seperate queries up first. one that just `WHERE length = 0 ORDER BY banid DESC` and the other `WHERE length <> 0 ORDER BY (timeleft calculation)` and then merge them in code but that is rubbish.

Comment: You could use `UNION` to merge them in SQL.

Comment: I've never understood UNION, do you have an example on how to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split it, and `UNION` them:

```
(SELECT * FROM rp_bans WHERE length > 0 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10) 
UNION
(SELECT * FROM rp_bans WHERE length = 0 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10)
```

You have to `LIMIT` them; from the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html):

> However, use of ORDER BY for individual SELECT statements implies nothing about the order in which the rows appear in the final result because UNION by default produces an unordered set of rows. Therefore, the use of ORDER BY in this context is typically in conjunction with LIMIT, so that it is used to determine the subset of the selected rows to retrieve for the SELECT, even though it does not necessarily affect the order of those rows in the final UNION result.

I found that taking a `LIMIT` higher than the result works as well.

Comment: I was trying to figure out how to do it, as well as come with an example.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question

Comment: My answer orders by length and by banid descending if length is 0. Tested it and works.

Comment: Tried it didn't give the result i'm searching for, i updated the initial question so i hope it clarifies is better

Comment: I'm confused, i would expect this to be correct. Yet it makes totally no sense now. I have set this as the order: `ORDER BY ('time' + 'length' - UNIX_TIMESTAMP()) ASC` of the first query. And if i run it i will get the result ordered on `length`. How is that even possible

Comment: Are the separate queries' results OK?

Comment: Yes but when i use the UNION it screws everything

Comment: It is because `UNION` gives an unordered set. See my updated answer.

Comment: wierd stuff a well it works indeed but i think i will take a little different approach. ty

Answer (score 1):

try it like that

```
ORDER BY IF(length=0, length DESC ,(`time` + `length` - UNIX_TIMESTAMP()) DESC )
```

EDIT:

```
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN length=0 = 0 THEN length END DESC,
 (`time` + `length` - UNIX_TIMESTAMP())  DESC
```

EDIT:

```
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN length != 0  THEN length END ASC,
CASE WHEN length =0 then time END  DESC
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99a9e/21)

Comment: Tried it didn't give the result i'm searching for, i updated the initial question so i hope it clarifies is better

Answer (score 0):

Change the `ORDER BY` to

```
ORDER BY length = 0, banid DESC
```

Note that your query will always do a full table scan due to the `OR` clause.

This query will perform better:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM rp_bans
    WHERE
        removed = 0
    AND
        length = 0
UNION ALL
    SELECT *
    FROM rp_bans
    WHERE
        removed = 0
    AND
        length > 0 AND (time + length) > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
ORDER BY length = 0, banid DESC
```

if you add the following index:

```
ALTER TABLE rp_bans ADD INDEX removed_length_time (removed, length, time);
```

A working example is at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45fa6/2/0

Comment: Tried it didn't give the result i'm searching for, i updated the initial question so i hope it clarifies is better